# Shopware PWA custom route

Tags: php, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, shopware, vue-storefront

I've create a custom Store route inside Shopware 6 as a plugin.
It shows up in the `store-api/_info/swagger.html` url.

What is does is it return an array with static text for now.

Now is my question, how would i call this url inside the pwa with vuestorefront.
I created a page inside `src/pages` but i cant wrap my mind around how to call the url to ge the data.

Do i need to specify the whole url in the axios? I cant find any documentation about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You approach so far is correct.

1. Create a new Store API route to fetch data from Shopware
2. Create a new Nuxt page by creating a page in `src/pages`.

Now we only need to connect the dots.

Nuxt pages are simply Vue components, so you can use the [`invokePost`](https://shopware-pwa-docs.vuestorefront.io/landing/resources/api/shopware-6-client.invokepost.html) or [`invokeGet`](https://shopware-pwa-docs.vuestorefront.io/landing/resources/api/shopware-6-client.invokeget.html) methods from the `shopware-6-client` package to call your custom endpoint.

You could also use axios to do it, but then you'll need to handle additional parameters (e.g. passing the correct `sw-context-token` or `sw-access-key` manually.